# Ember Cli and ASP.NET webapi - hooking the data up

Tags: json, ember.js, asp.net-web-api, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a an Ember Cli project that runs on the localhost:4200 and an asp.net webapi project that runs on  localhost:56967. Both projects run fine seperatly: I can start up my Ember app and test several routes, looks fine and I can visit my api (for example: api/products) and i see my response.

The problem I'm having is hooking the two things up with each other.

Adapter

```
 export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
      host: 'http://localhost:56967',
      namespace: 'api'
 });
```

I first ran into some Cors-problems, but i fixed the contentSecurityPolicy in my Ember app and enabled Cors on my Api.

When I go to the products route I can see the request to the Api gets accepted and the Api replies the Json answer. However, I'm failing to serialize the model so I can use it in my Ember App.

This is my response from the Api

```
  [{"ProductId":1,"Name":"Product 1","Description":"Category 1"},{"ProductId":2,"Name":"Product 2","Description":"Category 2"},{"ProductId":3,"Name":"Product 3","Description":"Category 3"}]
```

Ember model for a product

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name : DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Asp.net model for a product:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I know I have to serialize the Api response to make it "readable" Json for my Ember App. The question now: is it better to change the formatting on the Api? Or make a good serializer? How would I go about making the serializer? It's hard to find some decent tutorials. I tried this but that's not working:

```
 export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
      primaryKey: 'productId'
  });
```

This is the error i'm getting:

```
  Error while processing route: products No model was found for '0' Error: No model was found for '0'
```

**EDIT**
After trying the suggested serializer and some ASP.NET serializers as well I still couldn't get it to work. Today I found this project : http://jsonapi.codeplex.com/. It's a Nuget Package that helps the output of your ASP.NET API to be complient with the json.api standard. I got this working with my Ember-data in no time. Just add the correct header in your rest adapter that it looks like this:

```
 import DS from 'ember-data';

 export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
       host: 'http://localhost:57014',
       namespace: 'api',
       headers:{
          "Accept": "application/vnd.api+json"
        }
 });
```

And in your Asp.net model just add

```
[JsonObject(Title="product")]
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

It will pluralize your output to this:

```
{
"products": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Product 1",
        "description": "Category 1"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Product 2",
        "description": "Category 2"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Product 3",
        "description": "Category 3"
    }
]
}
```

It's still in Alpha state but looks promising. A small note on the pluralization: it just adds the -s to your model name, something to keep in mind.

Comment: Do you mind going into more detail about how you got JSONAPI working with ember js? Did you use the ember-json-api (https://github.com/kurko/ember-json-api)? I've been trying to get this to work for days and any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

The main issue is that Asp Web API returns the following response:

```
[
  {
    "ProductId":1,
    "Name":"Product 1",
    "Description":"Category 1"
  }
]
```

But Ember Data expects the server to respond with the following format instead:

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "productId": 1,
      "name": "Product 1",
      "description": "Category 1"
    }
  ]
}
```

You could update the response from the Web API server to be in the format that Ember expects, but it's easier to create a Serializer in Ember to map the data from Asp Web API into Ember's format.

I [wrote a detailed blog post](http://blog.yodersolutions.com/using-ember-data-with-asp-net-web-api/) that explains how to create an Ember Serializer to perform this mapping.

Be sure to read the blog post to understand what is going on in the Serializer. But as a reference, here is what I believe your serializer should look like:

```
App.ProductSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: 'productId',

  extract: function(store, primaryType, payload, id, requestType) {
    if (payload.length) {
      for (var i = 0; i < payload.length; i++) {
        this.mapRecord(payload[i]); 
      }
    } else {
      this.mapRecord(payload);
    }

    payloadWithRoot = {};
    payloadWithRoot[primaryType.typeKey] = payload;

    this._super(store, primaryType, payloadWithRoot, id, requestType)
  },

  mapRecord: function(record) {
    for (var property in record) {
      var value = record[property];
      record[property.camelize()] = value;
      delete record[property];
      return record;
    }
  },

  serializeIntoHash: function(hash, type, record, options) {
    var recordJSON = record.toJSON();
    for (var property in recordJSON) {
      var value = recordJSON[property];
      hash[property.capitalize()] = value
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I get a couple of errors on this: a couple of semicolons missing, payloadWithRoot is not defined (so you have to make it a var first i guess?) - besides that - super read on your blog, clarified a lot! Is it better to use one serializer for all models? or a specific one per model? Are relations handles properly with this as well?

Comment: I've been trying to convert the ToDo app (https://github.com/xqiu/MVCSPAWithEmberjs) to use your method, but I've been unsuccessful. The example app uses extractArray and extractSingle in the RESTSerializer. (https://github.com/xqiu/MVCSPAWithEmberjs/blob/master/MvcSPAWithEmberjs/App/models/TodoList.js) Using your approach, do I still need to implement those methods or does your code make those methods irrelevant? Thanks!

Comment: It seems like a huge overkill to write serializers for each model and for each navigational property for a huge application. This is essentially what the ember spa template does.

Comment: The blog post linked to by @paul comes up 404 but if you follow this link http://blog.yodersolutions.com/?s=using+ember+data+with+asp.net it's, currently, the only search result.